# How to login with php and stream context to other website

Tags: php

I want to read information from a other website,
but tis site is protected by a loginform. I have username(e-Mail adresse) and password, now I want to login with a php program.

I tried to use stream context, but it doesn't works and I get with file_get_contents only the data of the login form and not the data of the target site.

```
<?php
$url="https://wsm2.cegelec-asp.de/index.php";
$user="username"; //e-Mail adresse
$password="password";
$auth = base64_encode("$user:$password");
$data = array(
'http' => array(
'method'=>'GET',
'request_fulluri' => true,
// ignore_errors can help debug – remove for production. This option 
added in PHP 5.2.10
'ignore_errors' => true,
'header' => "Authorization: Basic $auth")
);
$context = stream_context_create($data);
$response = file_get_contents($url, 0, $context);
echo $response;
?>

<?php
//$fileurl contains page to validate
$validateurl="https://wsm2.cegelec-asp.de/index.php";
$username='username'; //It's a e-mail adresse
$password='password';
$cred = sprintf('Authorization: Basic %s',
base64_encode("$username:$password") );
$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>'GET',
'header'=>$cred) 
);
$ctx = stream_context_create($opts);

$validate=file_get_contents($validateurl,false,$ctx);
echo $validate;
?>
```

In both examples I get only the data of the login form, I see only the login form. I want to see the target site with the informations, that I want to copy.